How to Prove That Any Open Connected Set in $\mathbb{R}^n $ Has Property $(P) $?
I am studying a property $(P)$ of open subsets $\Omega$  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , defined as follows:
An open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ has property $ (P) $ if, for every $ \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega) $(the space of smooth functions with compact support in $ \Omega $) such that $ \int_{\Omega} \varphi(x) dx = 1 $, and for every $ u \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega) $, there exists $ v \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n) $ such that:
$
u = \operatorname{div} v + \varphi \int_{\Omega} u(x) dx,
$
where $ \operatorname{div} v = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i} $.
I am trying to solve the following questions:

Prove that any open connected set $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ has property $(P)$.
The idea seems to involve decomposing $\Omega $ into smaller subsets (e.g., rectangles) for which $(P)$ is easier to verify, and then extending the result to $ \Omega $ using partitions of unity and connectedness. However even when studying the case just for $\Omega = (0,1)^n$, I am unable to construct a $v$ that solves the problem.

Show that $ v $ can be chosen to depend continuously on $u$ and $\varphi$.
I believe the explicit construction of $ v $ for rectangles can help, but I am unsure how to formalize the continuity of $v$ as a function of $u$ and $\varphi$ .

Let $ \Omega $ be a connected open set in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ u \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega) $. Show that $ \int_{\Omega} u(x) dx = 0 $ if and only if there exists $ v \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n) $ such that $ u = \operatorname{div} v $.
This seems to be related to the divergence theorem and the definition of property $ (P) $, but I am unsure how to construct $ v $ explicitly when the integral vanishes.


Could someone provide a detailed and rigorous explanation of these steps? Any references to relevant methods or theorems would also be appreciated.

Note that $g  = u - \varphi \int u$ satisfies $\int g = 0$, so 1. follows from 3.


can be proved using the Poincare duality, while to do 2 you might need some PDE (Poisson formula)

